# Error output when running a postfix container

Tags: docker, email, postfix-mta

I have the following in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  simplemail:
    image: tozd/postfix
    ports:
      - "25:25"
```

So far, so good. But I get the following output when I run `docker-compose run simplemail`:

> rsyslogd: cannot create '/var/spool/postfix/dev/log': No such file or
>   directory rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg):
>   Operation not permitted. rsyslogd: activation of module imklog failed
>   [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ] rsyslogd: Could no open output
>   pipe '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory [try
>   http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]  * Starting Postfix Mail Transport
>   Agent postfix                         [ OK ]

What can I do to fix the errors above?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/tozd/postfix) for the `tozd/postfix` image states:

> You should make sure you mount spool volume (/var/spool/postfix) so
>   that you do not lose e-mail data when you are recreating a container.
>   If a volume is empty, image will initialize it at the first startup.

your docker-compose.yml file should then be:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  postfix-data: {}

services:
  simplemail:
    image: tozd/postfix
    ports:
      - "25:25"
    volumes:
      - postfix-data:/var/spool/postfix
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After making the suggested changes, I'm now down to three errors:

`rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted.`
 and 
`rsyslogd: activation of module imklog failed [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]`
 and 
`rsyslogd: Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]`